# an open subspace of compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is know that every compact subspace of Hausdorff space is closed and every closed set is compact.

So I have a question as folows: is there any compact non-Hausdorff space $X$ such that every open subspace of $X$ is compact?

Comment: It's not that every closed set is compact. In $\Bbb R^n$, a set must be closed and bounded in order to be compact.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any compact non-Hausdorff space X such that every open subspace of X is compact?

Let $X$ be your favorite set with the trivial topology.  Every subset of $X$ is compact, including the open ones.

Answer (score 0):

Any set endowed with the cofinite topology is compact, and all of its subspaces are compact.

Another example is $k^n$ with the Zariski topology, where $k$ is any field.